# "Info.plist" could not be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm running Xcode version 7.1 (7B91b) on OSX El Capitan 10.11.1
I just cloned a fresh version of Swift2 application to my local computer but it somehow refuses to build.

I've already performed the recommended steps:
- Shift + Command + K to clean up the build and objects.
- Update the plist path in the Build Target settings (triple checked)
- Check if the Plist file is actually present in the Xcode Project folder.

The project is using Parse as a backend and all the associated files and SDKs have been installed.

What am I overlooking? Seems like the problem is fairly persistent, and there are only a limited set of solutions posted, none of which solves the actual problem. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

That error occur because of some mistypo. Open that file as source code and find out where mistypo is.

Answer (score 0):

Path to the Info.plist was wrong. It compiled fine on my friend's machine because all the linking files were local.

I could not personaly build with references to non-existent directories. I found out via the Compiler Flags window.

The temporary work around was to create a new Xcode project and copy the files to Xcode from OSX folder.